# Trying to SUM two columns ia a query using php/html tables - Updated

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $db1 = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $db2 = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $sql = "SELECT 
                * 
            FROM joblist
            WHERE customer = :customer"; 

    $sql_val = "SELECT customer, 
                        SUM(value) AS total_value 
                FROM  joblist                       
                GROUP By customer";

    $sql_bal = "SELECT customer, 
                    SUM(balance) AS total_balance
                FROM joblist
                GROUP By customer";

   //var_dump($sql_bal);


   $customer = $_POST['customer'];
   $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
   $statement->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $statement->execute();
   $result = $statement->fetchAll();

   // total SUM for value   

   $stmt = $db1->prepare($sql_val);
   $stmt->execute();
   $totalv = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

   $sumv = array_sum(array_column($totalv, 'total_value'));

   var_dump($totalv);


   // total SUM for balance

   $stmt1 = $db2->prepare($sql_bal);
   $stmt1->execute();
   $totalb = $stmt1->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
   $sumb = array_sum(array_column($totalb, 'total_balance'));
   //var_dump($totalb);

   } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
       die();
       }

 }
```

[Table image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWeFc.png)

Ok I've got the array for total_value and total_balance grouped by customer.

I need to know how and have been told by others to use a derived table or a sub select query, but I'm not sure how to as of yet.

Anyone able to help me with this.. it's likely quite simply, but I'm to new to all this

Here is the table example I just need the sum for value and balance columns.
[link to current code](https://pastebin.com/NJZ2MRgd)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to sum the 2 columns you would like to use:

```
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = "SELECT * , (SELECT SUM(value) FROM joblist AS total_value GROUP BY customer) AS `value`
        FROM joblist
        WHERE customer = :customer" ;

    $customer = $_POST['customer'];
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':customer', $customer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Get the sum 
    $sum = array_sum(array_column($result, 'value')) + array_sum(array_column($result, 'balance'));
} catch(PDOException $error) {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```

Alternatively, you may also do this in your query (afaict):

```
SELECT 
  joblist.*, 
  (SELECT SUM(value+balance) FROM joblist AS total_value GROUP BY customer) AS `value`
FROM 
  joblist
WHERE 
  customer = :customer
```

Hope this helps,